# TikZ artifact when graphing (and shading) functions of y

Tags: pgfplots, fillbetween

I'm trying to make a simple plot of two functions (of y) and shade the area between them. When I use the shading plot, I get an artifact in the picture. I've tried changing the bounds and splitting the shading plots into two (or sometimes three or four) and they all spit out some kind of artifact that messes with the picture. What can I change or finesse to make this artifact go away?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=1,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$
    ]
    \addplot[name path=f(y),smooth,black,mark=none,
         domain=-0.23:1.1,samples=40] (12*x*x-12*x*x*x,x);
    \addplot[name path=g(y),smooth,black,mark=none,
         domain=-0.23:1.2,samples=40] (2*x*x-2*x,x);
     \addplot [blue!50!,opacity=0.4] fill between[of=f(y) and g(y),soft clip={domain y=-0.166:1}];
    \node at (1.1,0.15) {\footnotesize $f(y)=12y^2-12y^3$};
    \node at (-0.85,0.9) {\footnotesize $g(y)=2y^2-2y$};
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. If I make a file with `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{pgfplots} \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11} \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween} \begin{document} <your code> \end{document}` I do not get any such artifact. Do you see the same problem in that minimal example?

Comment: Right, the code should be completed, i.e. with preamble and end, so we don't need to speculate ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To long for the comment ...

I cant reproduce your "artifact". In test i use  a bit clean-up and shortened of your code fragmnet. I extend it as you can see below to an MWE (Minimal Working Example):

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    minor tick num=1,
    axis y line=center,
    axis x line=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
% new
    enlarge x limits,
    domain=-0.23:1.1, samples=40, 
    smooth,
    ]
\addplot[name path=f(y)] (12*x*x-12*x*x*x,x);
\addplot[name path=g(y)] (2*x*x-2*x,x);
\addplot [blue!50!,opacity=0.4] 
    fill between[of=f(y) and g(y),soft clip={domain y=-0.166:1}];
\node at (1.1,0.15) {\footnotesize $f(y)=12y^2-12y^3$};
\node at (-0.85,0.9) {\footnotesize $g(y)=2y^2-2y$};
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]